# Storing Image in VCard and reading from it in android code manually

Tags: android, base64, vcf-vcard

I am creating vCard files from my android app.
I am storing data manually(without using any libray)
I am able to write the data,read and parse it in my app.But when I save Image .I have gor two issues.

1)I am not able to save the image captured using camera..which throws an Out of memoery exception while writing the base 64 encoded string into vcard.

2)I am able to save the base 64 encoded string of some image which I took from gallery,but while reading it doesn't get me image.I am reding all the data from vCard line by line and base64 encoded string is not coming as a single line.(Please note that I stored each value to the file using \r\n)

Please let me know the proper way of doing this.

Code Snippets

Encoding

```
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                encodedProfileImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Writing

```
fw = new FileWriter(vcfFile);
```

...

```
fw.write("PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=PNG:"+encodedProfileImage + "\r\n");
```

Reading and decoding

```
else if(strline[0].equals("PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=PNG")){
                                 String imagestr=strline[1];
                                 byte[] byteArray = Base64.decode(imagestr, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                 card.profileImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

                             }
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading it in you can use BitmapFactory.Options

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

Use the decodeByteArray call that takes BitmapFactory.Options as the last argument.

if you set  inSampleSize = 2

It will reduce the size of the incoming image to something managable.

```
  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inSampleSize = 2; //Scale it down
  options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RBG_565; // Less memory
```

Comment: Still no luck. I tried with URL too. In that case I am able to save it and parse it, but I am not getting the image in Contacts.